# Why $[\forall x \neg \alpha \rightarrow \neg \alpha^{x}_{c}] \longrightarrow [\alpha^{x}_{c} \rightarrow \exists x \alpha]$ is a tautology?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $c$ be a new constant symbol in the language. Then $[\forall x \neg \alpha \rightarrow \neg \alpha^{x}_{c}] \longrightarrow [\alpha^{x}_{c} \rightarrow \exists x \alpha]$ is a tautology.

This means the expression is always $\textbf{true}$ regardless of the truth assignment of all the prime formulas, which assume the form of $\forall y \beta,$ occuring in it.

Every wff in the  expression is built from  formulas of the form: $\forall z \beta,$ via the operations $\rightarrow$ and $\neg.$ So how do I build $\neg\alpha^{x}_{c}$ from $\forall y \beta \ ?$ And how do I assign a truth value on it?

Kindly advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The formula :

> $(∀x¬α → ¬α^x_c) \rightarrow (α^x_c → ∃xα)$

is a *valid* formula of *first-order* logic.

Usually, the use of *tautology* is restricted to *propositional logic*.

But we have also another prossibility : we can say that a formula of *f-o* logic is an *instance* of a tautology, in which case it is obviously valid.

To show this, we must assume that $\exists$ is an abbreviation for : $\lnot \forall \lnot$.

Start then from the tautology :

> $(\varphi \rightarrow \lnot \psi) \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \lnot \varphi)$

and instantiate it with $∀x \lnot \alpha$ in place of $\varphi$ and $\alpha^x_c$ in place of $\psi$.

We have :

> $(∀x¬α → ¬α^x_c) \rightarrow (α^x_c → ¬∀x¬α)$.

With the above abbreviation, we conclude with :

> > $(∀x¬α → ¬α^x_c) \rightarrow (α^x_c → ∃xα)$.

Thus, we have proved that the formula is *valid*, exactly because it is an *instance* of a *tautology*.

---

*Comment*

If you want to use a "semantical" argument, based on *truth assignment*, again you have to start form :

> $(∀x¬α → ¬α^x_c) \rightarrow (α^x_c → ¬∀x¬α)$.

Assume an *assignment* $v$ such that $v(\alpha^x_c)=F$; then the consequent of the "main" conditional is *true* and the formula evaluates to *true*.

Assume now an *assignment* $v$ such that $v(\alpha^x_c)=T$.

We have two possibilities :

- if $v(∀x¬α)=F$, then $v(¬∀x¬α)=v(∃xα)=T$, and the consequent of the conditional is *true*; then, the formula is *true*.
- if $v(∀x¬α)=T$, then $v(¬∀x¬α)=v(∃xα)=F$, and the consequent of the conditional is *false*; but then, $v(\alpha^x_c)=T$ means that $v(¬\alpha^x_c)=F$, which implies that also the antecedent of the conditional is *false*. Thus, the formula is again evaluated to *true*.